# К какой части предложения относятся слова "твердое покрытие"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*В границах водоохранных зон запрещаются:

движение и стоянка транспортных средств (кроме специальных транспортных средств), за исключением их движения по дорогам и стоянки на дорогах и в специально оборудованных местах, имеющих твердое покрытие.*